# Jump from try to except using python

Tags: python, try-catch, break

I searching the way to break the try and go into the except
(This example has an syntaxerror in the break line)

```
def fool():
    return 0

try:
    var = fool()
    if var == 0:
        pass  # from here jump to except 
except:
    fool2()
```

Another way i thought is:

```
var = fool()
if var == 0:
     fool2()
```

Another solution more pythonic ?

Comment: You can always raise, but what problem are you trying to solve by jumping to the except?

Comment: instead of `if var == 0:` you could use the more pythonic `if not var:`. But what is the original task? Exceptions are only for exceptional cases...

Comment: `not` is good to use for booleans (`True`/`False`) and `None`, but I think it is confusing to test integers with `not`, it just makes it unclear what type of variable it is you're testing. `== 0` is the good choice imho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can raise a generic Exception:

```
try:
    var = fool()
    if var == 0:
        raise Exception
except:
    fool2()
```

But this is not good programming: you should always be clear on which exceptions you're going to catch.

The [Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) states that "Errors should never pass silently".

So, this could be a better implementation:

```
class FoolException(Exception):
    pass

def fool():
    if everything_ok:       
        return 0
    raise FoolException()


try:
    var = fool()
    if var == 0:
        raise FoolException() 
except FoolException:
    fool2()
```

This will prevent you to catch unwanted exceptions (e.g. IndexError, ZeroDivisionError...)

BUT, I think the best pattern here is to call fool2 separately:

```
def fool():
    return 0


try:
    var = fool()
    if var == 0: #Here I manage controlled events
        fool2()
except: #Here I manage uncontrolled events
    fool2()
```

This way is even better, because it isolates the instruction which can raise exceptions:

```
def fool():
    return 0


try:
    var = fool()
except: #Here I manage uncontrolled events
    fool2()
else:  #Here I manage controlled events
    if var == 0:
        fool2()
```

Comment: I guess it's a philosophical debate about how to answer bad questions: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201207/bad_answers_on_stack_overflow.html

Answer (score 3):

You can't jump from the try clause to the except, except by raising an exception as other answers have shown.  But that's strange and you shouldn't do it.  Instead, re-think your control flow.  What are you trying to accomplish? There's a natural Python structure that will let you do it, and try/except probably isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
     var = fool()
     if var == 0:
       raise Exception
 except:
     fool2()
```

Answer (score 0):

### General Answer:

Short/Simple but probably not best way would be:

```
try:
    if <condition>:
        raise ValueError
except:
    pass  # some code
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try using raise.

```
fool():
   return 0

 try:
     var = fool()
     if var == 0:
       raise Exception('Things are not going well')
 except:
     fool2()
```